# Python save embed base64 pdf string into file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, base64

I have html document embeded with pdf document in `base64` encoded format.  I like to extract the string and save it as pdf file. using below code to save it as pdf file.

but its on opening in adobe reader, saying invalid format. looking to fix this issue.

I think pdf file encoded using Javascript `encodeURIComponent` function. need to convert using Python.

**sample embed tag**

```
<embed  type="application/pdf" src="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9D">
```

**Code**

```
import base64


def decode_b64():
    b64 = "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9D"
    buffer = BytesIO.BytesIO()
    content = base64.b64decode(b64)
    buffer.write(content)

    with open(Path(Path.home(), 'Downloads', 'mytest.pdf'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(buffer.getvalue())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    decode_b64()
```

**=== Update 1:**

found the way to convert using JavaScript: It will be nice if we can port this code to Python.

```
const {readFileSync, writeFile, promises: fsPromises} = require('fs');

var data=readFileSync("pdf-file.html", 'utf-8')
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var parser = new DOMParser();
const virtualDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/html');

var elem = virtualDoc.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
    var attrib = elem.attributes[i];
    if (attrib.specified) {
        if( attrib.name == "src") {
            var result =attrib.value
            result=result.replace('data:application/pdf;base64,','');
            
            let buff = Buffer.from(decodeURIComponent(result), 'base64');
            writeFile('pdf-file.pdf', buff, err => {
                if (err) {
                  console.error(err);
                }               
              });            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That file IS damaged.  It has been truncated.

Comment: @TimRoberts Its long string, thats why I didn't include it in this sample code

Comment: Then there's not really much we can do.  That string is certainly the START of a PDF file.  There are two variants of base64: one that is URI safe, and one that is not.  Do you know which one your Javascript is using?

Comment: Its using Javascript function `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the pdf file, looking for Python function to decode this string. let me also try to decode in Javasript itself

Comment: The basic Base64 alphabet only uses + and /.  `encodeURIComponent` encodes both of those.  So, you just need to learn what it replaces them with, and do a Python `.replace` to put the original characters back in.

Comment: @TimRoberts I found some work around, first I need to use javascript `decodeURIComponent` function then take this string in  `Java`  and use `Base64.decodeBase64` method to decode the string to pdf.

Comment: @TimRoberts added JavaScript code in my original post

Comment: That's exactly what I said.  You need to decode the URI parts.  Only two characters in base64 get encoded.  You should be able to figure out their encoding by looking at the base64 string itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation that you should have been able to chase down yourself.  I wasn't 100% sure how Javascript encoded those two characters, so I wrote up a simple HTML page:

```
<script>
var s = "abcde++defgh//";
alert(encodeURIComponent(s));
</script>
```

When I ran that page, the result was `"abcde%2B%2Bdefgh%2F%2F"`, and that is all the information you need to fix up those strings.

```
def decode_b64():
    b64 = "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9D......"
    b64 = b64.replace('%2B','+').replace('%2F','/')
    content = base64.b64decode(b64)

    with open(Path(Path.home(), 'Downloads', 'mytest.pdf'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(content)
```